# Magento Access Denied error on frontend

Tags: php, magento

I'm not sure if this is purely magento related but I'm getting an access denies error when I try to load up a staging Magento site.

I uploaded a zip to the staging directory of the site and unzipped it and followed these steps for setting the site's permissions:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \; 
find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \; 
find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \; 
find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
chmod 700 includes
chmod 600 includes/config.php
```

The error ist just Access Denied and nothing more so it's a pain to try to debug.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Magento is doing my head in!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste the error output?

Comment: The only error is Access Denied. Should I be looking elewhere? That's what appears when I load up the site.

Comment: You have `chmod`ed but not `chown`ed.  Are the files owned by the correct user? Anything in the web-server logs?

Comment: How do I check if the files are owned by the correct user?

Comment: What is the ownership on other files that *can* be accessed on the web-server? `ls -la`. You really need to check your web-server logs and post something.

Comment: Sorry, how do I check this? I'm working on a project on updates to a site that another developer had set up.

Comment: Is it all urls or specific ones.. Can you get to the base url?

Comment: Secondly, var and media need chmod -R 777 permissions with full permissions to var Magento does not run correctly or at all

Comment: Just throwing this out there, but do you have an .htaccess file?  If so, is it the default Magento one?

Comment: @Rob I ended up changing the permissions on everything to see if it would work and it does now but clearly not ideal. It was all URLs just in the staging subdirectory.

Comment: @espradley Yep it was the right one, I think permissions need to be changed on it too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the DB if you are cloning a system or set up the DB's table "core_config_data". I hope be helpful for you.

Comment: Oh yes that's been done too. I had a copy already running but was encountering a seperate error so decided to copy over the fles again.